# Is there a single word for describing a person as unbiased in self judgement?

Tags: single-word-requests

An example sentence might read something like:

> Tom was a *[unbiased self judge]* and thusly suitable for the task.

or

> Barbara's *[lack of bias in self judgement]* convinced her the pink elephants were in fact real.

*etc.*

I tried all the tricks I know to get an answer from Google's Search, but to no avail. And not that it's really worth a damn, I have a gut feeling there *should be* a word that fits the bill.

The subject could be described as possessing this attribute, and perhaps also as being one of these.

Any suggestions, or edits to improve this question will be as appreciated as any answers. Thanks.

Comment: Would *candor or sincerity* fit?

Comment: I think that Tom and Barabara are very different. Tom presumably has integrity and a realistic grasp of the situation whereas Barabara seems to be deluded - presumably she wouldn't be 'suitable for the task'. Could you pin it down a bit more?  Thanks.

Comment: Something along the line of "self-aware", I'm thinking.

Comment: There is no word for it because there is no such thing.

Comment: Additional question - Did you mean Barabara has a ***lack*** of bias as you stated, or did you mean she is in fact biased?

Comment: In psychology, to the best of my knowledge, it would be described as a realistic self-concept or an unbiased self-concept. The alternatives have terms like self-enhancement bias, negative self-concept, etc. Though my experience in this area is limited, it was something I studied formally, so I hope it's not just my self-enhancement bias saying: If I don't know of such a word, their probably ain't one.

Comment: Thanks @Josh61 - "Candor" led me down a long path to "sound" which is simply very close. An antonym for "delusional" might be perfect.

Comment: @JimReynolds -- The problem is that it's so rare -- only you and I exhibit this characteristic -- that there's been no real need to name it.

Comment: @JimReynolds A full answer explaining that "unbiased self-concept" is perhaps as close as one might get to a *single word* whilst hitting the nail square on the head, would get my upvote. It's a sad fact, that inspired a great song, that *"you can't always get what you want"*. I accept that.

Comment: @RegDwigнt - *"Unicorn"*. Impressive cynicism, but this isn't a philosophy forum.

Comment: I was thinking effectively the same thing Fred: Words can describe what doesn't exist. However to be unbiased, I must admit that unicorns and pink elephants *might exist* and that they *might not exist*. Anyway, even though this isn't a philosophy forum, the subject can help improve the question. I would suggest changing Barbra's example to "Barbara's [lack of bias in self judgement] convinced her that the only thing she could be certain of is '[I think therefore I am](https://www.britannica.com/topic/cogito-ergo-sum)'." You'll have fewer conformists complaining Barbra's incredible claim then.

Comment: @Tonepoet - Yeah, Babs' experience has ruffled some feathers for sure, but essentially, there's nothing wrong with the sentence as an example. Unfortunately, there's no *reason* beyond my own interest for this question, and thusly (snigger) no *better* example to offer except any other one could care to create. Since the question is about her *"self-concept"* and not about the elephants, I see no good reason to edit - and importantly - much water has passed under that bridge.

Comment: I suspect what you're trying to describe is seeing things from different perspectives or different angles, and the word I'd use is open-minded

Comment: I think that the sentence "Tom had a rare capacity for realistic self-appraisal that made him suitable for the task" may express what you have in mind in your first example. But as chasly from UK notes in a comment above, your second example invites a very different word choice; I'd be inclined to fill in the blank there with "delusional thinking" or "lack of critical judgment."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The adjective **objective** and the noun **objectivity** are close fits, but may not be exact fits for what you're after.

The second definition on [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/objective) for objective as an adjective is:

> not influenced by personal feelings, interpretations, or prejudice; based on facts; unbiased:

This would give:

> Tom was **objective** and, thus, suitable for the task.

You would probably want to go a little farther than that.

> Tom had a reputation for being **objective** and was thus suitable for the task.

The second sentence seems to be asking something else and it might help to clarify. First, we'll put the word in there...

> Barbara's **objectivity** convinced her the pink elephants were in fact real.

Maybe this would work...

> Barbara's **objective** perception of reality and hallucination convinced her that the pink elephants were in fact real.

Comment: If the object of the objectivity was clearly the "self" of the person with it, this would be pretty much perfect. But *e.g.* It's not clear in what regard Tom is objective. It could be about something else. It's specifically that he is objective about himself that I'm after. Any thoughts?

Comment: Objective has that sense as well. One connotation of objective is being able to look at oneself objectively, to weigh the evidence presented without bias and determine if it is credible.

Answer (score 1):

"Disinterestedness" has the sense of a general lack of selfish motives.

Comment: I rather like this understated dark horse. It serves pretty much exactly to disambiguate *"objective"* and *"impartial"*. Nice one :-)

Answer (score 1):

I venture that something like

> *unbiased self-concept*

or replacing *unbiased* with *realistic* or *impartial,* is about as close as we may get to an answer.

If I'm proved wrong with a precise single word that means prdcisely this and only this, I'll at least pretend to be delighted.

Psychologists--especially social and clinical psychologists--have recognized that most people display the "self-enhancement bias" by work of which about 80+% of people rate themselves as being higher than average on most socially valued characteristics. Some argue that it is usually or often healthy or adaptive for us to see ourselves as "better" than we actually are. Others think that those of us who see each other more realistically have the adasntage.

Of course, there are also people who have negative self-concepts, which is generally associated with depression and anxiety problems.

Answer (score 0):

I believe **nonpartizan** will be a right word here to use.

> Tom was a nonpartizan and thus suitable for the task

and

> Barbara's nonpartisan nature convinced herself that the pink elephants were in fact real.

UPDATED : I misread Barbara's nature.
Nonparti**san** is an Adjective a quality while Nonparti**zan** is noun that means a person.

Comment: But Barabara is also non-biased (lacks bias) according to the question.

Comment: That has too specific a meaning for what the OP is requesting. You can't be nonpartisan about yourself unless you have Multiple Personality Disorder.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK Oh thanks! I just didn't notice that, Updated the answer!

Comment: I'm finding "...zan" to be nothing more than an alternative spelling for "...san". Although I *like* the word, I have to agree with @Robusto - the word seems best used to refer to another subject, not one's self. A link to a reliable source defining "...zan" would be appreciated.

Comment: @FredGandt [here](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/nonpartisan) you can find the meaning and examples as well. I believe as far as I can dig, one can be nonpartisan for a situation and that might involve 'yourself' as well!  and in [this](http://www.washingtonpost.com/lifestyle/style/2016-campaigns-are-beefing-up-staffs-so-are-the-media-who-will-cover-them/2015/02/23/9f1d2152-a66b-11e4-a7c2-03d37af98440_story.html) article you can fins the usage of the word that means ** to be partisan**

Comment: @sud007 The first link you've provided shows "...san" and "...zan" to be alternative spellings of the same word, with (obviously) the same meaning, which in that case is very specifically about political affiliation. The second link is blatantly about politics. I appreciate the effort, but I think this is a non-starter.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps *self-aware*. *Oxford Dictionaries Online* defines *[self-awareness](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/self-awareness#self-awareness)* as

> Conscious knowledge of one’s own character, feelings, motives, and desires:
>   *the process can be painful but it leads to greater self-awareness*

Comment: A problem is that developmental psychologists use the term to denote the emergence of an ability for toddlers to develop an awareness that we are objects distinct from others and our environment. Lewis M, Brooks-Gunn J. *Social cognition and the acquisition of self.* NY: Plenum; 1979.

Comment: I think it's fine unless you're working in child development. Lots of words have obscure technical senses we usually ignore.

Answer (score 0):

Enlightened, or enlightened being, is the term for one who has no, or almost no, judgement.

Comment: Someone who has almost no judgement is the opposite of enlightened. I think you mean to say something else, but you should also include an explanation and reference.

Comment: No, I do not mean to say the opposite of what I have said. I mean to say what I have said. Judgement, the habit of describing things as 'good: or 'bad' is the enemy of higher consciousness, which instead, accepts and acknowledges what is there, rather than judging it. You can find this idea in Buddhist teachings, which recommend 'acceptance'.